# Library for datatable in fastapi

Tags: datatables, fastapi

I am relatively new to fastapi and need to server side pagination and filtering  for datatable.
For frontend we are using python django framework ..
What would be the best way to implement ?
Which library should I be using?.

.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What exactly have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .. asking for recommendations is specifically off-topic for SO https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251134/ , so writing your Question in a form where you've _tried_ some library(ies) and know what they don't do for you which you need will get much better Answers and avoid closing!

Comment: django is generally a backend / everything included framework; how are you using it together with FastAPI? Have you tried using something like `fastapi-pagination` which does a bit of the work for you? https://uriyyo-fastapi-pagination.netlify.app/ - regardless, pagination should be quick to implement yourself, so exactly where did things stop?